# Get current size of IPython window

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to make a progress bar. I'm trying to make it fit perfectly with the `ipython` window. The number of elements in the progress bar would depend on the width of the window. For instance:

```
print('loading' + '-----'*window_width//2)
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Is there a `COLUMNS` variable available in the environment? Shells usually set that.

Comment: Nop, but I found another way. See answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.get_terminal_size()
```

```
Out[1]: os.terminal_size(columns=33, lines=9)
```